# How to pass the value of checkbox to function using Angular?

Tags: angularjs

In my Razor view I am using Angular and trying to pass the value of a checkbox to  function.

When the following input is checked"

```
<label><input id="divpriority" ng-model="priority" type="checkbox" />
  Select all - high priority
</label>
```

This input is changed:

```
<label><input class="tablePriority" ng-checked="priority" type="checkbox" />
   High priority
</label>
```

Now I am trying to pass the value(true/false) in the above input to a function:

```
<td><br/><br/>
  <button id="enqueuebtn"  type="button" ng-click="Enqueue(priority)" 
          class="btn-primary">Enqueue</button>
</td>
```

This is not working as priority is undefined when I am debugging my JavaScript.

How can I pass the value `true`/`false` to function `Enqueue` when the second input is checked ?

In my JavaScript I have:

```
$scope.Enqueue = function (isPriority, ) {
    debugger;
```

While debugging idPriority is undefined.

Comment: Post your JavaScript too.

Comment: can you post more HTML code too, or maybe a jsfiddle?

Comment: New AngularJS developers often do not realize that `ng-repeat`, `ng-switch`, `ng-view`, `ng-include` and `ng-if` all create new child scopes, so the problem often shows up when these directives are involved. See [nuances of protoypical inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs).

Answer (score 0):

Priority should be available in your controller, since you are binding to it.  So from your edit, this line is not needed:

```
 $scope.priority = isPriority;
```

since $scope.priority should *already* reflect the value of the checkbox.

Comment: I am getting the same undefined value for priority. priority just not have a value

Comment: you do not have to pass priority.  Remove the parameter from the function and just call Enqueue().

Comment: Thanks Phil, but I would like to pass it because the priority checkbox is on several rows in a table so I need the value of the the checkbox on the selected row

Comment: Is this is all happening within an ng-repeat, you should post that code and make it part of your question, otherwise it's hard to give you good advice.

Comment: the check box is independent of the ng-repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Added model to second input

```
<label><input ng-model="ispriority" class="tablePriority" ng-checked="priority" type="checkbox" />High priority</label>
```

Then pass model to function:

```
<td><br/><br/><button id="enqueuebtn"  type="button" ng-click="Enqueue(ispriority)" class="btn-primary">Enqueue</button></td>
```